# Python socket intermittently refusing connections

Tags: python, sockets, connection, timeout

I have a python socket accepting connections (frequent connects/disconnects, multiple connections per second)...

Code:

```
class ThreadedServer(object):
  def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = "0.0.0.0"
    self.port = 9999
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

  def listen(self):
    self.sock.listen(5)
    while True:
      client, address = self.sock.accept()
      client.settimeout(3)
      threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

  def listenToClient(self, client, address):
    client.sendall("Welcome\r\n")
    client.close()
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
  port_num = 9999
  ThreadedServer('',port_num).listen()
```

Once the server starts initially, it's very fast to respond but after a short while, I start to get connection timeouts when the server should accept new connections....

For example:

```
root@bugsbunny:/srv# telnet localhost 9999
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.
Welcome
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@bugsbunny:/srv# telnet localhost 9999
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

I have checked the obvious things I can think off, and it doesn't look to be a server issue...

Limits:

```
root@bugsbunny:/srv# cat /proc/28038/limits 
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             514903               514903               processes 
Max open files            65535                65535                files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       514903               514903               signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us        

Used FDs:
root@bugsgunny:/srv# ls /proc/28038/fd | wc -l
845
```

Anyone have some idea as to what is going on here?

Thnx.